# Get firstName and lastName from Full Name persisted in MongoDB in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, npm

I am trying to get separate firstName and lastName from the FullName for learning purpose. When I go to run this application I get two error a)Mongoose Schema Student has a 'firstName' virtual b) Mongoose Schema Student has a 'lastName' virtual

Below is the code I am debugging

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  courses: [{ type: String, ref: 'Course' }]
});

/* Returns the student's first name, which we will define
 * to be everything up to the first space in the student's name.
 * For instance, "William Bruce Bailey" -> "William" */
schema.virtual('firstName').set(function(name) {
  var split = name.split(' ');
  this.firstName = split[0];
});

/* Returns the student's last name, which we will define
 * to be everything after the last space in the student's name.
 * For instance, "William Bruce Bailey" -> "Bailey" */
schema.virtual('lastName').set(function(name) {
  var split = name.split(' ');
  this.lastName = split[split.length - 1];
});

module.exports = schema;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `Mongoose` documentation,

**Virtuals**

> `Virtuals` are document properties that you can `get` and `set` but
>   that do not get persisted to `MongoDB`. The `getters` are useful for
>   formatting or combining fields, while `setters` are useful for
>   de-composing a single value into multiple values for storage.

As you have the `name` property persisted in the DB, you should use `getters` to split it as `firstName` and `lastName` whereas you can use `setters` to define `name` property from `firstName` and `lastName`.

So your code for `virtuals` should be,

```
/* Returns the student's first name, which we will define
 * to be everything up to the first space in the student's name.
 * For instance, "William Bruce Bailey" -> "William" */
schema.virtual('firstName').get(function() {
  var split = this.name.split(' ');
  return split[0];
});

/* Returns the student's last name, which we will define
 * to be everything after the last space in the student's name.
 * For instance, "William Bruce Bailey" -> "Bailey" */
schema.virtual('lastName').get(function() {
  var split = this.name.split(' ');
  return split[split.length - 1];
});
```